# use amazon EC2 ami tools and EC2 api tools at the same time?

Tags: amazon-ec2, bash, amazon-web-services

Amazon has two toolsets that have to be used for ami creation [ec2 api tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) and [ec2 ami tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/368) which both require EC2_HOME environmental variable to be set. So it seems like I can only use one of them toolsets at a time in a single terminal? and if I have to use another toolset - I have to export EC2_HOME variable to correct location every time I need to witch toolset - is this correct?

What would one do if I want to use both toolsets from single terminal. Iknow that I can open multiple terminals and setting EC2_HOME to various location that way - but it seems like a bit contr-productive.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I install the standard `ec2-api-tools` and `ec2-ami-tools` packages on Ubuntu, things just work.  I do this with:

```
sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools ec2-ami-tools
```

When I install the EC2 API tools and AMI tools manually by downloading them from the pages you indicate (e.g., when I need the very latest versions) then I simply copy the contents of each bin, lib, and etc directory in to a single location like:

```
/usr/local/aws/bin/
/usr/local/aws/lib/
/usr/local/aws/etc/
```

Copy/move/extract all bin, lib, etc files and subdirectories from both EC2 downloaded zip files into those locations and then set a single envariable value (add this to `$HOME/.bashrc` or equivalent):

```
export EC2_HOME=/usr/local/aws
```

Once this is done, all commands should work from both sets of tools.

Here's my recipe for the tools you want to install:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/aws

wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2-api-tools.zip
unzip ec2-api-tools.zip
sudo rsync -a --no-owner --no-group ec2-api-tools-*/{lib,bin} /usr/local/aws/

wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2-ami-tools.zip
unzip ec2-ami-tools.zip
sudo rsync -a --no-owner --no-group ec2-ami-tools-*/{lib,bin,etc} /usr/local/aws/
```

You can also drop in the RDS tools, IAM tools, and the rest of the AWS command line tools.

Comment: just curiuos - ami tools also have etc directory. when I unzuip it. it that smthg important? should it also be copied perhaps? ther is only some publkic cert and 6 or some manifest files.

Comment: Stann: Good point.  I've added etc to the recipe above and simplified the rsync commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is vague and therefore probably not going to be me any rep, but in short, if you look at the man page for the tools you  are using I think you will find that there are other ways to supply the variables than setting an environment variable. You can probably use command line switches to supply the variables each individual tool needs.